# How to get exact record count for an Object using SOQL for more than 1 million record

Tags: apex, soql, count

I would like to know how many records are there for a given Object. I have written code (SOQL) which can show record count for <= 50000 records but I have 2 Million records then how can I get an exact count.

FYI: I also used a read-only attribute in a VF page, but it can read up to 1 Million records.

Comment: you just want count of your records ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Use Aggregate query

```
public class Test_Aggregate{
        public static void TestAgg() {
            Integer intCount = 0;

            for(AggregateResult result :[SELECT COUNT(Id) intVal FROM Custom_Object__c])
            {
                intCount+=(Integer)result.get('intVal');
            }

            System.debug('No of records are: '+intCount);
        }
    }
```

---

### 2. Use Readonly notation

**@ReadOnly** only work with JS remoting. If you direct call the method using class instance then it wouldn't work

Here is the example(IN this example I have 97000 Task records.)

```
<apex:page controller="TestVFpage">

    <div id="totalAccounts"></div> 
                <script>
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.TestVFpage.getTask}',
                        function(result){
                            alert('Total Records: '+result.length);
                        }

                    );
                </script>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class TestVFpage {
    @RemoteAction
    @readOnly
    public static list<Task> getTask(){
        return [SELECT Id FROM Task];
    }
}
```

alert message 
[image]

### 3. Use rest api using jquery.

```
<apex:page>
   <input name="getList" class="btn" value="Get Account list" type="button" onclick="getSobjectList()" />
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      var sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
      function getSobjectList() {
      $j.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/services/data/v35.0/query?q="+''+"{!URLENCODE('SELECT count(Id) totalTask FROM Task')}",
      headers: {"Authorization" : "OAuth " + sessionId},
      crossDomain : true,
      dataType: 'application/json',
      success: function (responseData) {
      console.log(responseData);
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
      console.log(request.responseText);
      }
      });
      }
   </script>
</apex:page>
```

check browser console

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ratan, your first approach solved my problem but the rest 2 failed for records >= 1000000